# Can I use try-with-resources with an InputStream that has already been created?

Tags: java, inputstream, try-with-resources

Like this:

```
public void myMethod(InputStream fileIn){
    try (InputStream in = fileIn)  {
        do stuff....
    }
}
```

It seems to work. Is it safe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It seems to work

It will do if you add `InputStream` (or some supertype of `InputStream`) before `in`: the [language spec requires](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) you either to declare a variable for each resource.

```
try (InputStream in = fileIn) { ... }
```

or just refer directly to `fileIn`, in Java 9+:

```
try (fileIn) { ... }
```

And there's no reason why it shouldn't work: with the variable declaration form, you are assigning an expression to the variable (a new class, the result of a method invocation, an array element etc). The resource can't see if it is getting a "new" instance or not: it's just a thing with a value of the correct type.

> is it safe?

Depends what exactly you mean by "safe".

It is certainly safe in the sense that it will work without error in this code, and `in.close()` will be invoked at the end of the block.

However, it violates the rule of thumb that "if you didn't open a stream, don't close it". As such, it might be unsafe in the sense that it causes unexpected failures in other parts of the program that expect the stream still to be open after invoking the method.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that was a typo on my part, I do have `try(InputStream in = fileIn)`

Comment: I've fixed the question

Comment: Maybe I'll need to rethink my strategy in terms of opening/closing streams then. Thanks again!

Comment: It is just a rule-of-thumb; there is nothing to say that you need to follow it. The slightly more general form is "if you don't *own* a stream, don't close it"; but Java has no notion of ownership of a reference, so you have to manage this yourself. If you intend for `myMethod` to "take ownership" of the stream, it is fine to close it here.